# How can I predict a value given an arbitrary input and having a list of input/output (using only javascript)? Maybe Neural Networks?

Tags: javascript, neural-network, tensorflow.js

I have a list of input/output pairs (about 75 values). Here is an extract:

```
{input:[2], output: [120968] },
{input:[4], output: [108241] },
{input:[7], output: [78138] },
{input:[12], output: [49590] },
{input:[13], output: [48821] },
{input:[17], output: [45958] },
{input:[21], output: [37111] },
{input:[26], output: [34037] },
{input:[33], output: [29948] },
{input:[34], output: [29383] }
```

The bigger the input, the smaller the output would be. The function used to get the output is unknown. This needs to be calculated using JavaScript.

I want to get the output for any arbitrary number (even if it's not listed. For example: what would be the output for input:[3]?)

The first thing I thought about was neural networks. I had a look at several libraries and found brain.js It looked simple enough but the output I get needs to be a value between 0 and 1 so I can't really use it.

I also found a basic example using TensorFlow.js that seemed to be just what I needed:

Example I found

```
 const callbacks = {
        onEpochEnd: async (epoch, logs) => {
          console.log("epoch: " + epoch + JSON.stringify(logs))
        }
      };

    // Generate some synthetic data for training.
    const xs = tf.tensor2d([[1], [2], [3], [4]], [4, 1]);
    const ys = tf.tensor2d([[1], [3], [5], [7]], [4, 1]);

    // Build and compile model.
    async function basicRegression(){

      // Build a sequential model
      const model = tf.sequential();
      model.add(tf.layers.dense({units: 1, inputShape: [1]}));
      model.add(tf.layers.dense({units: 1, inputShape: [1]}));
      model.compile({optimizer: 'sgd', loss: 'meanSquaredError'});

      // Train model with fit().
      await model.fit(xs, ys, {epochs: 100, validationSplit: 0.1, callbacks: callbacks});

      // Run inference with predict().
      model.predict(tf.tensor2d([[5]], [1, 1])).print();
  }

  // Create a basic regression model
basicRegression();
```

But If I use the numbers on my list, the script no longer works:

MyNumbers

```
const callbacks = { onEpochEnd: async (epoch, logs) => { console.log("epoch: " + epoch + JSON.stringify(logs)) } };

// Generate some synthetic data for training.
const xs = tf.tensor2d([[2], [4], [7], [12], [13], [17], [21], [26], [33], [34]]);
const ys = tf.tensor2d([[120968], [108241], [78138], [49590], [48821], [45958], [37111], [34037], [29948], [29383]]);

// Build and compile model.
async function basicRegression(){

  // Build a sequential model
  const model = tf.sequential();
  model.add(tf.layers.dense({units: 1, inputShape: [1]}));
  model.add(tf.layers.dense({units: 1, inputShape: [1]}));
  model.compile({optimizer: 'sgd', loss: 'meanSquaredError'});

  // Train model with fit().
  await model.fit(xs, ys, {epochs: 100, validationSplit: 0.1, callbacks: callbacks});

  // Run inference with predict().
  model.predict(tf.tensor2d([[5]], [1, 1])).print();

}

// Create a basic regression model basicRegression();
```

This is the result I see on the console:

```
epoch: 0{"val_loss":161917157502877700,"loss":4760350208} tryit.asp:16:19
epoch: 1{"val_loss":null,"loss":44930980028350460} tryit.asp:16:19
epoch: 2{"val_loss":null,"loss":null} tryit.asp:16:19
epoch: 3{"val_loss":null,"loss":null}
.
.
.
epoch: 99{"val_loss":null,"loss":null} tryit.asp:16:19

Tensor[[NaN],]
```

*Note that the original example works fine and the only thing I did was exchange the numbers on the array.

I am not familiar with TensorFlow so, is there anything I need to change to make my values work with the example? Is Is there another way that is not Neural Networks to solve the problem?

Thank you in advance.